# Will reference $scope object diretctly to service cause Memory leaking? ionic

Tags: angularjs, memory-leaks

I found that angular service/factory singleton is a great way of sharing data between controllers(to retrieve data or to modify data of one controller from other controllers) . However, if I use it in this way, will I be running into memory leaking situations.

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('test')
  .factory('cacheService', cacheService);

  cacheService.$inject = ['$q'];

  function cacheService() {

    var cacheObj = {};

    var service = {
      set:set,
      get:get
    };

    return service;

    function set(scopeObject) {
      if(angular.isObject(scopeObject)){
      cacheObj = scopeObject;
      }
    }

    function get(){
      return cacheObj;
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: _" service/factory singleton is a great way of sharing data between controllers"_ Then what's the point of injecting a scope?

Comment: @zeroflagL. thx for your comment. I am still a noob. I don't understand what you mean, Can you pls elaborate ?

Comment: Data can be shared either using a service or a (parent) scope. I don't understand why you would use both at once.

Comment: @zeroflagL. Sorry for the confusing  of using a name like this "scopeObject".  I use this service to save data like this from my controller: $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave', function () {
    CacheService.set($scope.blogs);
  });  And I get data from another controller like this: $scope.blogs = CacheService.get()